# is there much benefit of using timeout policy in polly when sql command or connection has timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, timeout, polly

I am trying to refactor some old code and realised that I don't really understand polly. This is the code:

```
var timeoutPerTry = Policy
    .TimeoutAsync(context =>
    {
        ////enlarge timeout every time it happens

        taskTimeoutInSeconds = (int)(timeoutMs / 1000);

        Log.LogVerbose(
            $"log something");
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMs);
    }, TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic);

// retry SqlException up to MaxRetries
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<SqlException>()
    .RetryAsync(Constants.MaxRetries,
        (response, calculatedWaitDuration, context) =>
        {
            Log.LogError(
                $"Failed dynamic execution attempt. Retrying. {response.Message} - {response.StackTrace}");
        });

try
{
    ////combine timeout policy and retry policy
    var combinedPolicy = retryPolicy.WrapAsync(timeoutPerTry);
    // ReSharper disable once AccessToDisposedClosure
    var results =
        await combinedPolicy.ExecuteAsync<IEnumerable<T>>(async () => {

            var connectionString = ConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionString(warehouseId);
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  // assumed no need for using block as closed by caller
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand
                {
                    CommandType = commandType,
                    CommandTimeout = taskTimeoutInSeconds, // in secs
                    CommandText = "JerrySimulateSlowSp"
                })
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                    cmd.Connection = connection;

                    using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {
                        return mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<T>>(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    return results;
    //cmd.Connection = null;        
}
catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == -2)  // -2 is a sql timeout
{
    throw new ThunderTimeoutException(Constants.HttpResponseTimeoutSql);
}
catch (TimeoutRejectedException)
{
    throw new ThunderTimeoutException(Constants.HttpResponseTimeoutTask);
}
```

We can see that we created two polices, one timeout policy and another one is retry policy to handle retry.

The code within is a basic SQL Command and SQL data reader.

I am wondering as I can set timeout on SQL command and connection string also have timeout anyway, is there any benefit of using a polly timeout policy?

If I just rely on the timeout from sql command and connection string, I will just need a retry polly policy. For me, that seems to be something easier and less coding as well.

Answer (score 1):

Each timeout has its own purpose:

- `SqlConnection`'s `ConnectionTimeout`: Terminates the connection attempt if the threshold is exceeded

  - Default: 15 seconds
- `SqlCommand`'s `CommandTimeout`: Terminates the command execution attempt if the threshold is exceeded

  - Default: 30 seconds
- `Polly`'s `TimeoutPolicy`: Terminates the provided delegate execution attempt if the threshold is exceeded

As you can see the timeout policy exposes an overarching constraint which include the connection establishment, the command execution and the result mapping.

---

Let's suppose you set the timeout policy's limit to 45 seconds. There is still a chance to fail with timeout

- Connection is established in 14 seconds << no timeout
- Command is executed in 29 seconds << no timeout
- Mapping took more than 2 seconds >> timeout

So, whether you need this or not depends on what you want to achieve.